# Legacy Business Connector error in Tridion 2011

Tags: 2011, 5.3

I'm currently working with the legacy Business Connector in Tridion 2011. I create a new Web Reference in my Visual Studio Project and run the following code

```
var requestXml = ...;
var client = new com.myorganisation.tridion2011.BusinessConnector();
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword", "mydomain");
var response = client.execute("default", requestXml, null);
```

The response is

> LCould not load Java runtime libaries at C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll

<strike>I'm running 32 bit Windows 7 so the `jvm.dll` is installed to `C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre6\\bin\\client\\jvm.dll`. I presume something thinks I am running a 64 bit version.</strike>

I have both the 32 and 64 bit versions of Java installed on my server and have verified this by running `java -version` in both Program Files directories

```
C:\Users\kevinbrydon>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java" -version
java version "1.6.0_35"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01, mixed mode)

C:\Users\kevinbrydon>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java" -version
java version "1.6.0_35"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 20.10-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

When I use the web service associated with my old version of Tridion (5.3) everything works fine, the response is as expected (adds a new component)

```
var requestXml = ...;
var client = new com.myorganisation.tridion53.BusinessConnector();
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword", "mydomain");
var response = client.execute("default", requestXml, null);
```

Has something changed or is there a configuration setting I must modify?

Comment: Can you try by having both 32-bit as well as 64-bit version of JRE installed on your machine togather?

Comment: @PankajGaur Is that sensible? I'm not sure the installer would let me and even if it did, my computer is 32 bit.

Comment: Your statement is quite ambiguous in the question "I am running a 64 bit version when in fact I am running 32 bit windows 7"..can you update your question with  simple statement

Comment: @PankajGaur You've taken that quote out of context. But whatever, I guess the original sentence could be clearer.

Comment: You should install both 32-bit and 64-bit JRE on the system where your Tridion is installed, not on your client Windows 7 machine. Your client need no Java at all to talk to BC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a known issue with the Business Connector with Java v6.  According to [the online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_242A17EC385644C8A77F2C976576492C) (login required):

> The Business Connector does not work with Java 6 if msvcr71.dll is not
> accessible from the system path

This is caused by a known bug with Java:  https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6509291

The online docs describe the solution as:

> The workaround for this bug is to place the file msvcr71.dll in the same folder as the launcher executable.

Comment: This worked! I put the `dll` in \%TRIDION_HOME%\bc\. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Go to your CMS server and ensure you have both 32-bit and 64-bit version of JRE installed on it. Additionally, check they are working correctly -

**For 64 Bit:**

1. Open command prompt and navigate to `C:\Program File\Java\jre6\bin`
2. Execute java -version command here and see it getting executed without any error and telling you the expected JRE version

**For 32 Bit:**
Repeat the above procedure but instead `C:\Program File\Java\jre6\bin`, go to `C:\Program File <x 86>\Java\jre6\bin`